# select values of a particuliar date from a SQL table to Flash

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript-3

I've got a SQL table with 100 lines. Each line got a date.

I'd like to retrieve the info for a particular date.

Example :
With Flash, the user select the date 12/11/2014 and the AS3 code will display all the values (each columns of my table) that match this date.
In this example it will display "firstname : As de trefle, tome 1 : 10...etc" as it's the only entry that matches this date.

So far I've managed to select variables, in AS3, from users name, like that :

```
memberCombo.prompt = "Please select a user";
memberCombo.addItem( {label: "as de trefle" } );
memberCombo.addItem( {label: "kathy" } );
memberCombo.addItem( {label: "peter" } );
memberCombo.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, checkComplete);

function checkComplete(evt:Event):void {

    // Create A new URLVariables instance to store the variable
    var myVariables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();

    // Create a variable (e.g. candidate) to send
    myVariables.username = evt.target.value;

    // Create a new URLRequest instance sending data to "ascom01.php"
    var myRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.example.com/sql_result.php");

    // Send data using the POST method
    myRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

    // The data property of the request is set to the
    // URLVariables instance (myVariables) to send to the PHP file.
    // Note: myVariables stored the variable (e.g. candidate)
    myRequest.data = myVariables;

    // Create a new instance of the URLLoader class to work with.
    // URLLoader.load( ) method should be used when we need the 
    // sent variables returned back to Flash ActionScript.
    var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader;

    //specify dataFormat property of the URLLoader to be "VARIABLES"
    //This ensure that the variables loaded into Flash with the same variable names
    myLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;

    //Load the PHP file by using URLRequest
    myLoader.load(myRequest);

    //Listen when the loading of data COMPLETE
    //Call the loadComplete function when the loading COMPLETE
    myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete);

}

// This is the function that display the data returned back from PHP file
function loadComplete(evt:Event):void {

    //Display the value with variable name "totalItem"
    total_txt.text = evt.target.data.totalItem

    //Get the value (string) with variable name "phpConfirm"
    var myResult:String = evt.target.data.phpConfirm;

    //Split the string into an Array
    var myArray:Array = myResult.split("|");
    //output_txt.text = "The number of items are: " + myArray.length;

    var finalString = "";
    var i:int;

    for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        finalString = finalString + myArray[i] + "<br>";

    }

    output_txt.htmlText = finalString;
}
```

And in my sql_result.php:

```
<?php

$username = $_POST['username'];

// create connection
$connection = mysql_connect("****.perso", "root", "root") or die ("Couldn't connect to the server.");

// select database
$db = mysql_select_db("dbase", $connection) or die ("Couldn't select database.");

// create SQL
$sql = "SELECT domain FROM d_table where username = '$username'";

// execute SQL query and get result
 $sql_result = mysql_query($sql, $connection) or die ("Couldn't execute query.");

// get number of rows in $result.
 $num = mysql_numrows($sql_result);

$phpConfirm = "";


$counter = 0;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result)) {

 $domain = $row["domain"];
 if ($counter == 0) {
 $phpConfirm .= $domain;
 } else {
 // Use a item limiter "|" to seperate the records
 $phpConfirm .= "|" . $domain;
 }

 $counter++;
 }


echo "phpConfirm=" . $phpConfirm . "&totalItem=" . $num;


// free resources and close connection
 mysql_free_result($sql_result);
 mysql_close($connection);

?>
```

How can I retrieve the variables with the date and not the username ?

And, more complex, how can I use both ? (example : I choose the date AND the username "John" and it shows me all the variables of my table where the date and the username matches ?

Thank you for your help,

---

EDIT

So, I've changed in my AS3 code the labels by these :

```
memberCombo.prompt = "Please select a date";
memberCombo.addItem( {label: "2015-06-23" } );
memberCombo.addItem( {label: "06/23/2015" } );
memberCombo.addItem( {label: "23-06-2015" } );
```

and in my php code :

I've changed

```
$username= $_POST['username'];
```

by

```
$date = $_POST['date'];
```

and

```
$sql = "SELECT domain FROM d_table where username = '$username'";
```

by

```
 $sql = "SELECT domain FROM d_table where date = '$date'";
```

But it seems that my flash app doesn't find any "domain" with this date.
No error. It just doesn't find anything.

Any idea why ?

Comment: I think your using MySQL not SQL-Server, due to your code. I'll remove the wrong tag from your question.

Comment: Absolutely right. My mistake. Sorry.

Comment: @user3094896 To find rows according to date, you have to change your sql request to use the date : `where your_date = '12/11/2014'` !

Comment: Ok. but it seems that my AS3 code doesn't reconize the date format... (I've edited my post)

Comment: I've add `trace(myRequest.data)` and it seems that it's, indeed, a format problem as the result of this trace is `2015%2D06%2D23` and not `2015-06-23`